# GTX750 only 640x320 screen resolution under WinXP SP3

Tags: windows-xp, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card

I just bought ASUS GTX750 2GB and UltraWide LCD Philips Brilliance 298P4QJEB/00 having huge 2560x1080 resolution - it looks and feels absolutely great and fine under Win7, BUT when I am trying using it under WinXP (unfortunately having recording studio and tons of WinXP only compatible stuff I am still in need for using this old OS) after installing the latest NVIDIA WinXP drivers for my VGA GeForce GTX750 2GBDDR5 (that is v358.87 2015.11.4) I stuck at ridiculous 640x320 resolution and there is nothing I can do with it!!!

I am using long quality 10m DisplayPort cable.

I further noticed that under monitor drivers it did not recognized my monitor listing it as anonymous PlugAndPlay, so I tried to install drivers that comes with my monitor but regardless of that it still using predefined WinXP Microsoft drivers (I already wrote to Philips waiting for their response about that).

Interestingly enough, when I uninstall NVIDIA drivers, voila: tho everything becomes extremely laggy every time I try to move any window BUT it detect and automatically set monitors to its appropriate native resolution of 2560x1080...strange, isn't it?

So: what is wrong here, please?

P.S.: I forgot to add that I OF COURSE FIRST SEARCH WEB - no success (all advices I have found there were useless, they had no effect whatsoever) + I also tried to add my own resolution in NVIDIA VGA Control Panel but it is not saved, it still shows only that 640x320 even in that advanced window of the NVIDIA Control Center.

Comment: You have tried Windows XP Mode or an equivalent VM, yes? It's very easy to activate if you have an old computer that still has a product key on the side. Have you also tried older drivers?

Comment: WTF are you talking about??? What WinXP mode, are you OK? I am insie \windows XP, there is no WinXP Mode needed, gee...very bad comment

Comment: Why are you still using Windows XP!? At least use a VM.